# setting variable from another class

Tags: c++, class, variables, object

I watched this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=jTS7JTud1qQ&t=7m57s and I can get the code to output a string easy, but I want the user to be able to set their own name and save it.

Sorry I'm really new to c++ so any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading more about input. The tutorials that you are watching will show you how to do it soon. If you are impatient, here is how it works.

```
string temp;
cout << "ENTER YOUR NAME: ";
cin >> temp;
bo.setName(temp);
```